# Запуск jar с помощью C#

Tags: c#, jar

Всем доброго времени суток. Долго ломаю голову (я в шарпах не спец), почему это не работает. Пытаюсь написать автотесты с помощью Coded UI в VS. Первый тест - открытие приложения. Пытаюсь выполнить его с помощью вызова джарника, но вместо открытия приложения мельком врубается командная строка и на этом всё заканчивается. Ранее боролась с ошибкой "Unable to access jarfile". Её, вроде, победила.
Собственно, проблемный кусок:

```
string filename = "C:\\Users\\lnen\\AppData\\Roaming\\kms 1.96\\java.wms.fx.jar";
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "java.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar" + filename;
proc.Start();
```

Comment: выглядит так, как будто пробелов в proc.StartInfo.Arguments маловато

Comment: Так как в пути есть пробел, нужно его в кавычки заключить: `"\"C:...jar\""`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо, но и с `string filename = "\"C:\\Users\\lnen\\AppData\\Roaming\\kms 1.96\\java.wms.fx.jar\"";` это не работает. Запускается командная строка и очень быстро закрывается. Само приложение не стартует, хоть тест и помечается как пройденный.